# Generic function to print an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, generics, printing, dynamic-arrays

I'm trying to write a generic function to print the elements of an array. This is what I have:

```
void printArray(void * source, int numElements, int size, void (*printFunction)(void *)){

     void *dest[numElements];
     memcpy(dest, &source, (size * nElem));
     int i;
     for (i = 0; i < numElements; i++){
         printFunction(dest[i]);
     }
 }
```

I am passing in the address of an array, the number of elements in the array, the size of each element in the array, and a callback function to handle printing/formatting for whichever type of array it is (the printing function works fine, I've tested it).

Right now it's printing out the first element, then I'm getting a segmentation fault. I'm having trouble figuring out what the problem is - any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm new to stackoverflow so let me know if I can improve my question.

Comment: `dest` is an array of void pointers. I don't think that's what you want. Try `char dest[numElements*size]` instead.

Comment: Please show how are you calling the function.

Comment: I can't fathom why you need to memcpy *anything* for this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you copying at all?

What you actually want is to pass a char pointer, that way you can increment it by 
`size` from `0` to `numElements` times, passing it to printFunction each time.

Notice, you've actually written a more general function than something that just prints an array. You're effectively writing a 'map' function that maps a function on to an array.

Something like this should work (note it's untested):

```
void printArray(void * source, int numElements, int size, void (*printFunction)(void *)){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < numElements; i++){
        printFunction(((char *)source) + i * size);
     }
}
```

Comment: The `char` pointer isn't needed as an argument. you can manufacture it via-cast from the original `void *source`. I.e. `printFunction((char*)source + i*size);` will suffice. Were I to change anything beyond that it would be to used unsigned types for `size` and `i`, preferably `size_t`.

Comment: Yes, but `char *` is as good as `void *` in the signature. If the OP wants, they can just cast as char *, but I don't see a reason why not to just put it in the signature to begin with. I agree with your size_t suggestion, though.

Comment: "why not to just put it in the signature to begin with" - the reason is simple, cast it once *in this function* or cast it **everywhere** this function is called with anything *other than a `char *`*. There is a reason universal functions (qsort, bsearch, etc.) take `void*`.

Comment: The `char *` in the argument list isn't as good as a `void *`; you have to convert (cast) pointers to `char *` explicitly, but conversion to `void *` happens automatically.  It is better to keep the `void *` in the argument list, but then create `char *src = source;` and use `src + i * size` thereafter.  But I agree 100% with the 'why copy at all' comment.

Comment: Ahh, good point. I forgot about the implicit conversion. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I was able to pass in `void * source` and then use `printFunction((void *)(source + i * size));` and that worked! Thank you @jack_rabbit @WhozCraig !

Comment: @auregirl You don't want to increment a `void *`. That's undefined behavior as far as I know. Maybe it works now, but it might well break later. Try using it for printing an array of chars.

Comment: @auregirl I don't advise that. `void*` pointer math is non-standard. We debated the cast-to char* for a reason.

Comment: Incrementing a void pointer is a GCC extension, not standard C.

Comment: Sorry - didn't see the additional comments about the cast to char. I agree it's probably safer to do it that way. I went ahead and casted to char and am now incrementing that instead and it still works. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that `source` is a `void *` to the start of the array (not to an array of pointers).  In that case...

There's no need to copy the array -- you can just work with `source` itself.  And since modifying function arguments in C is allowed and only affects the copy within the function, you can alter `source` and `numElements` as you proceed through the array.  With those points in mind, you can simplify your function to the following:

```
void printArray(void *source, int numElements, 
                    int size, void (*printFunction)(void *))
{
    for (; numElements; numElements--) {
        printFunction(source);
        source = ((char *)source) + size;
    }
}
```

The version above runs a `for` loop, decrementing `numElements` to give one pass per array element.  At the end of each pass, `source` is offset by `size` to get to the next element, after passing it to your callback function.  The `(char *)` cast is used to allow the pointer arithmetic even though `source` is a `void *`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a `char` array to alias your data, not a `void*` array. The latter is an array of pointers, which isn't a suitable type for a buffer.

A generic function should look more like this:

```
void printArray(void * source, int numElements, int size, void (*printFunction)(void *)){

     char dest[numElements*size];
     memcpy(dest, source, (size * numElements)); // source is already a pointer, don't address it
     int i;
     for (i = 0; i < numElements; i++){
         printFunction(dest[i*size]); //make sure you index based on the type and not just a single byte
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its even much simpler, no multiplication needed, just pointer arithmetic:

```
void printArray(void *source, int numElements, int size, void (*printFunc)(void *)){
  while (numElements--) {
    printFunc(source);
    source=(char *)source+size; //C forbids void* math. source+=size fails on MSVC
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
void printArray(void * source, int numElements, int size, void (*printFunction)(void *)){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < numElements; i++){
        printFunction((source + i * size));
    }
}
```

In your program you are saving source content to array of void pointers so you are getting segfault when you are printing. Instead you can directly using source, in order to fetch each element you have to add size to source.